# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status (-lcudnn)

Tags: linux, linker, gnu, ld

#### Edit 1

I forgot to mention that I want to use the theano library.

After I reached out to the admin, the cudnn modules were provided by them. However, I am still getting the same error.

```
$ module load devel/cudnn/10.2
$ python -c "import theano"
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:
/pfs/work7/workspace/scratch/ul_dco32-conda-0/conda/envs/my_env/bin/../lib/
gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudnn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Mapped name None to device cuda: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB (0000:3A:00.0)
```

```
$ vi $HOME/.theanorc
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cuda

[cuda]
root=$CUDA_HOME/bin

[dnn]
include_path=$CUDA_HOME/include
library_path=$CUDA_HOME/lib64

[lib]
cnmem=1
```

So, most probably, I have a link problem, however, I can't find it where.

#### Problem

I am struggling with `ld: cannot find -lcudnn`.

#### Description

I want to use Cuda and CuDnn for my project. I am working in a cluster, Cuda is installed in the cluster already (p.s. I don't have root permissions). So I copy the Cuda files into my local folder and install Cudnn as instructed on the official website. However, ld cannot find `libcudnn.so`.

```
$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
Release:        7.7
```

#### What I tried

```
$ ld -lcudnn --verbose
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libcudnn.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudnn.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libcudnn.a failed
ld: cannot find -lcudnn
```

If I add the library path of `libcudnn.so` manually

```
$ ld -L "$CUDA_HOME/lib64" -lcudnn
attempt to open /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so succeeded
-lcudnn (/home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so)
librt.so.1 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found librt.so.1 at /usr/lib64/librt.so.1
libpthread.so.0 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libpthread.so.0 at /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
libdl.so.2 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libdl.so.2 at /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2
libstdc++.so.6 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libstdc++.so.6 at /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libm.so.6 at /usr/lib64/libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libgcc_s.so.1 at /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found libc.so.6 at /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Here is my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64
```

ld somehow ignores `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Since I do not have the root permissions, I cannot either create a symbolic link or make changes in `ldconfig`. So, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the only way I can fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the problem was the theano configuration. Declaring the full path of CUDA_HOME (or CUDNN_HOME) than using $CUDA_HOME (or $CUDNN_HOME) solved my problem.

```
[cuda]
root=path/to/cuda/bin

[dnn]
include_path=path/to/cudnn/include
library_path=path/to/cudnn/lib64
```

P.S. The Cudnn and Cuda modules were installed by the admin, so one big hassle was gone.

Answer (score 0):

(This could have been a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that; I am talking only about the general linker etc usage, I don't know about the cuda or cudnn projects and what build tools they use, etc)

> If I add the library path of libcudnn.so manually
>
> ```
> $ ld -L "$CUDA_HOME/lib64" -lcudnn
> ```

This is a link line with no object files to link and create an executable with.

> ```
> attempt to open /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so succeeded
> -lcudnn (/home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcudnn.so)
>  :
> ```

This shows you got the right path into `-L`.

> ```
> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
> ```

This will be fixed once you use a proper link line perhaps by incorporating the `-L` path you have correctly specified above into the build process e.g. the `Makefile` or whatever else is appropriate.

> Here is my LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> ```
> $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> /home/ul/ul_student/ul_dco32/pkg/cuda/10.2/lib64
> ```
>
> ld somehow ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Since I do not have the root
>   permissions, I cannot either create a symbolic link or make changes in
>   ldconfig. So, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the only way I can fix it.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not for use by `ld` at link time, it is for telling `ld.so` the runtime linker (dynamic loader) where to look when searching for shared libraries to load into the running program.